# How to use kmeans clustering on a binary image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, k-means

I am trying to take binary masks say with two different people and everything else is black. Now I want to group each person into their own clusters using **K-means** so that I can eventually draw bounding boxes around them. Here is the code I have so far:

```py
def kmeans(img):
  k_values = range(1, 5)
  pixels = np.float32(img.reshape(-1,1))
  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
  flags = cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS
  min_ssd = 0
  for k in k_values:
    ssd,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(pixels,k,None,criteria,10,flags)
    if k == 1 or ssd < min_ssd: #looking for elbow in graph
      min_ssd = ssd
      min_labels = labels 
      min_centers = centers

  return min_labels,min_centers
```

As it stands, this code is returning the centers as pixel values and not coordinates so I am losing the spatial information in the frame. I am not quite sure how to change this code in order to obtain the cluster center as a point in the image and be able to visualize the clusters.

[image: Example photo]

**Edit:** I have changed the approach, first I start with OpenCV's `simpleblobdetector()` to detect the centroids of each blob in the image. From here I am initializing the centroids with those values. I plan to update the code when I finish making the changes

[image: Centroid detection]

### Final Code

```py
def kmeans_helper(img, centroids):
  data = np.nonzero(img)
  data = tuple(zip(data[0],data[1]))
  data = np.asarray(data).reshape(-1,2)

  num_clusters = len(centroids)
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = num_clusters, init = centroids, n_init = 1)
  kmeans.fit(data)
  centroids_array = np.uint8(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

  num_labels = np.unique(kmeans.labels_)
  clusters = [data[kmeans.labels_ == label] for label in num_labels]

  return clusters
```

I figured I would update my final code for anyone who might need this in the future.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the image as well so that we can work on your problem.

Comment: If you want centroids as coordinates, you should give kmeans coordinates. That is, do not pass the binary mask directly. For every pixel on the mask, you first have to generate an array of its coordinates.

Comment: @eldesgraciado So I would create an array of triples containing (x,y,pixel_val)?

Comment: I don’t know if you need to also include the pixel's intensity value - unless you are planing to do something with that info too. Just an array of `(x,y)` points should do the trick, `kmeans` will return each cluster's centroid also as an `(x,y)` array, and that should give you the centroid of each blob. Side note: if you are looking just for each blob centroid, you could also carry out component analysis and calculate the bounding box of each blob, from there it should be fairly easy to compute the centroids. You can also use central moments to compute blob centroids.

Comment: Connected components seems like a much better solution to do what you want to do. Or get bounding boxes for the contours from each binary blob.